# Can I interpret Django object values as JSON data within the JS script in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, chart.js

I've hit a bit of a stumbling block with a Django project having added a chart to a page using Chart.js only to find that it relies on the data inputted being in JSON format. I've researched ways of converting Django object values into JSON, such as serializing and re-writing my views, but for a number of reasons these aren't ideal options for me. Is there a way to convert Django object data to JSON data within the JS script?

I have an 'Accelerator' Django model with five separate decimal fields which ultimately need to be converted to JSON to feature in the chart. For each object created, the value of each field is prone to change (they are determined by a method calculating the mean value of separate values inputted into a separate model). I have an 'accelerator_detail' HTML template which renders and displays the various values of individual objects created using the Accelerator model.

This template is heavily reliant on Django placeholders and Python logic calling on object values, which is one reason why I'm hesitant about attempting to serialize the Django objects as JSON within my views (presumably this would mean I would have to re-write this template).

I've shared some of the relevant code below to provide a better understanding. Currently, the data key in my JS script is populated with dummy data but this is where my Django object values need to be stored:

```
// One of my model fields which needs converting to JSON
class Accelerator(models.Model):
    avg_mentorship = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=3)
@property
    def avg_mentorship(self):
        quantity = Review.objects.filter(subject=self)
        mentorship_result = Review.objects.filter(subject=self).aggregate(avg_mentorship=Avg('mentorship'))['avg_mentorship']
        return mentorship_result if len(quantity) > 0 else 0

// My accelerator_detail view
def accelerator_detail(request, pk):
    accelerator = get_object_or_404(Accelerator, pk=pk)
    reviews = Review.objects.all()
    context = {
        'accelerator': accelerator,
        'reviews': reviews,
    }
    return render(request, 'reviews/accelerator_detail.html', context)

// JS script within my HTML template
<script>
    var myChart = document.getElementById('accRatings').getContext('2d');
    var ratingsChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type:'horizontalBar',
        data:{
            labels:['Mentorship', 'Hiring', 'Community', 'Fundraising', 'Corporate Development'],
            datasets:[{
                data:[
                    4.1,
                    4.4,
                    3.9,
                    3.6,
                    4.2
                ],
            }]
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear why you think this could or should be done in the JS script. There's already a view sending your Django data to the template; that is where you should convert it to JSON.

Comment: I agree with @DanielRoseman. The data is already being served by your view. You can convert to output JSON in your view.

Comment: What I was trying to get across in my question was that I didn't want to convert all data to JSON via the view because much of my template calls on the django object and presumably converting the data to JSON would have rendered the template code unworkable?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't give this in a comment yet, have you looked into this yet? [Django Generic JSON views](https://pythonhosted.org/django-generic-json-views/). Seems to me like it would fit nicely into your project and help with the output you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already output by the view. You can just convert to JSON as you serve it from within the view.

Great example provided by [SimpleIsBetterThenComplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/27/how-to-return-json-encoded-response.html):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def profile(request):
    data = {
        'name': 'Vitor',
        'location': 'Finland',
        'is_active': True,
        'count': 28
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```